# Customising X-axis on Stacked Bar Graph GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I would appreciate some help with changing the axis titles given the format of my current ggplot.

I've tried the usual arguments such as scale_x_discrete() and adding the associated labels, yet with no success.

However, overall, my goal is to keep the current format of the stacked bar, yet change 1,2,3 on the x-axis to "Cluster A" "Cluster B" "Cluster C."

Would really appreciate if someone could show me how to encode this while keeping the current format.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("viridis")
install.packages("hrbrthemes")

library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)


x1 = rep(1:3, times = 5)
x2 = rep(0:4, times = 3)
x2 <- as.factor(x2)

df <- data.frame(x1,x2)
str(df)

ggplot(df, aes(x= x1, fill = x2), color = "x2") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  geom_bar(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE), stat="count") +
  theme_ipsum(axis = TRUE, grid = FALSE, axis_col = "black", axis_title_size = 10) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 11)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "B")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a continuous scale you have to set the `labels` and the `breaks` using `scale_x_continuous` or `scale_x_reverse`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
library(hrbrthemes)

x1 <- rep(1:3, times = 5)
x2 <- rep(0:4, times = 3)
x2 <- as.factor(x2)

df <- data.frame(x1, x2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x1, fill = x2), color = "x2") +
  geom_bar(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE), stat = "count") +
  theme_ipsum(axis = TRUE, grid = FALSE, axis_col = "black", axis_title_size = 10) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11, face = "bold"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 11)
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "B") +
  scale_x_reverse(breaks = 1:3, labels = paste("Cluster", LETTERS[1:3])) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ Stefan. I appreciate your help there. Thanks again